# How to change from "Read-Only" mode to "Standby / Read-Only" mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, recovery, alter-database

I changed the database (foo) mode from "Standby / Read-Only" to Active by using the following statement:

```
restore database foo with recovery
```

After that, I changed the mode back to Active by using the following statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE foo SET READ_WRITE
```

Then, I changed back to "Read-Only" by using user interface here:

Properties --> Options --> State --> Database Read-Only --> changed to 'True':

[image]

Now, I am trying to go back to the original state "**Standby / Read-Only**" mode (original).

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Read here for instructions and explanations:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3574/change-sql-server-log-shipped-database-from-restoring-to-standby-readonly/

Comment: @WhiteOwl I read the page but where is command to change "to Standby .."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go from Standby back to Restoring, but after recovery you can't go back to Restoring without restoring the backups again with norecovery.